# ldapmodify - can't add members to AD group

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group

I'm wanting to add members to an AD distribution group. I enter the following command (putting in dummy values in some places):

```
ldapmodify -v -h 111.111.111.11 -D "CN=binding_user,DC=example,DC=com" -x -w password -f entrymods
```

The file 'entrymods' contains:

```
dn: CN=group_name, OU=Groups, DC=example, DC=com
changetype: modify
add: member
member: CN=Smith\, John, OU=Users, DC=example, DC=com
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
ldap_initialize( ldap://111.111.111.11 )
warning: no attributes to change or add (entry="CN=group_name, OU=Groups, DC=example, DC=comchangetype: modifyadd: membermember: CN=Smith\, John, OU=Users, DC=example, DC=com")
modifying entry "CN=group_name, OU=Groups, DC=example, DC=comchangetype: modifyadd: membermember: CN=Smith\, John, OU=Users, DC=example, DC=com"
modify complete
ldap_modify: Invalid DN syntax (34)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090A5B, comment: Error processing name, data 0, vece
```

Comment: For others - the problem ended up being the file 'entrymods'. Make sure that you edit this file on linux - I was editing it on windows, and newlines weren't represented correctly. The commands listed above in 'entrymods' work fine if you manually input them into the command line (press enter after every line, press ctrl-d after last entry).

Answer (score 0):

Find a user without a Comma in their DN and try it again that way.  It is saying the referenced object does not exist.  Now I am not sure if it is the DN:
`CN=Smith\, John, OU=Users, DC=example, DC=com` (The member being added)

or the group DN:
`CN=group_name, OU=Groups, DC=example, DC=com`

Looking at the member DN being added, the comma (properly escaped, I would say) is easy enough to test and eliminate from being an issue if it was.